# Material Mode in Shading Panel

Tags: shaders

I have this version of Blender

[image]

What is the difference between the two Material modes in the Shading panel ?

[image]

[image]

On my PC  GLSL   seems to work, instead Multitexture  seems doesn't work.

Comment: Here's a document that explains some differences between a GPU based shader language (GLSL, HLSL, nVidia Cg) and the fixed-function pipeline. http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter05.html However, without you showing what you are seeing vs. what you expect to see, it's going to be difficult for anyone to guess what your issue is.